# Create a button in a Datagrid with Action Script 3 and Flex 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, button, apache-flex, datagrid, flex4.6

I have an application working with AS3 and FLex 4.6. I have a Datagrid automatically generated with some data, using :

```
var colonne:GridColumn = new GridColumn(DATAFIELD_NAME_LIBELLE);
colonne.headerText = "GPT";
datagrid.columns.addItem(colonne)
/*Building some others columns automatically*/
...
ligne = new Object();           
ligne[DATAFIELD_NAME_LIBELLE] = "Standard";
/*building some other rows and adding them to the right columns automatically*/
...
```

But i don't know how to add a button in a specific cell. I linked the grid i have in this image : [The grid i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/autvD.png), the "GridItem10662" is where i want to put my button. I tried with a button inside a GridItem but it's not working. Another problem is that i want in the first column, text for 1st and 2nd rows and a button for the 3rd row.

Maybe it can work with GridItemRenderer but i don't know how to work on separated rows in a same column.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can put both **Label** and **Button** into **GridItemRenderer** manipulating their visibility or/and scale by **data** or/and **rowIndex** values.

Comment: Can you be more precise on the **rowIndex** and **data** attributes ? Or link some documentation please ? 
I use : `spark.components.gridClasses.GridColumn` for my colums.
and this code for my case : 
`var gridItem = new GridItem();
    var myButton = new Button();
    myButton.label = "Hi guys !";
 
    gridItem.addChild(myButton);
    
    ligne = new Object();
    ligne[DATAFIELD_NAME_LIBELLE] = gridItem;
    
    dataProviderGridGPT.addItem(ligne);`

Comment: Ah, sorry, forgot to paste the link: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/gridClasses/GridItemRenderer.html#propertySummary Look for the examples at the very bottom.

Comment: Can i do that in the AS3 section of the code ? I want it to be automatically generated, i have severals differents cases for the same frame.

Comment: The second example shows you can use AS3  in the renderer. Also, I think you can make your own component inherited from **GridItemRenderer** with any wild behavior you want.

Comment: I did it with a custom GridItemRenderer ! Thanks !